# Merge [advanced-custom-fields] and [acf] tags

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, synonym-request

[advanced-custom-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields) (497 questions) and [acf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acf) (422 questions) are both referring to the same WordPress plugin. Having both tags seems redundant.

[advanced-custom-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields) has a better tag name and (currently) more questions, but [acf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acf) has more information in the tag wiki and excerpt.

I suggest merging or synonymizing [acf] to [advanced-custom-fields].

Comment: these two similar tags are still live after 8 months...

Comment: @Raptor (and Joe) this is now done, see post below and mod's comments on it

Answer (score 1):

Yes please. I came to Meta to ask for this and found this thread.

[acf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acf) has already been [officially suggested as a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/advanced-custom-fields/synonyms) of [advanced-custom-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields) but currently has 0 votes. I'm going to work on a few answers in advanced-custom-fields so I can get the required reputation to vote for it, **but it's going to need another 3 people to do the same**.

Unless - and this is why I came to Meta - it is possible for synonyms to be approved by moderators in cases where it's obvious? I realise the synonym voting system exists for a reason, but it does appear a bit difficult to achieve on a low-traffic tag. I have the required rep on [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) as a regular there, but I haven't answered enough questions specifically on the ACF tags yet.

For what it's worth, it's clear that both tags are being used for the same purpose. The [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/acf/info) [wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/advanced-custom-fields/info) both have similar descriptions, and as of right now, the newest posts on [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acf) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields) are all about the WordPress plugin rather than something else. There is one recent post that has *both* tags; the rest have only chosen one.

I agree with @Joe that advanced-custom-fields should be the primary tag:

- advanced-custom-fields currently has 654 questions and acf has 602
- advanced-custom-fields is the better name, it's much more easily recognisable
- the synonym has already been officially suggested by someone

I also agree the tag wiki for [acf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acf) is better, so I'm going to edit the [advanced-custom-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields) wiki to copy that useful information over.

Comment: Just to note: the wiki edit has been approved and the tags merged.